# Limit password reset emails sent in firebase

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I have a password reset function in my flutter app using firebase, how can I limit it to a few tries every ten minutes, I tried making it in the view but every time the user goes to another view it resets:

```
Future<void> passwordReset(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      widget.callTimesKey.currentState?.resetCallTimes(); // Reset callTimes using the GlobalKey

      // Add the current timestamp to the list of call times
      callTimes.add(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch);

      // Remove timestamps older than 10 minutes
      callTimes.removeWhere((timestamp) =>
          DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - timestamp > 600000);

      if (callTimes.length <= 10) {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .sendPasswordResetEmail(email: _emailController.text.trim());
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              content: Text(
                  'If this email exists in our system, a password reset email has been sent.'),
            );
          },
        );
        Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Pop the screen after showing the dialog
      } else {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              content: Text(
                  'Password reset requests limit exceeded. Please try again later.'),
            );
          },
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Text(e.toString()),
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

How can I save the tries count app-wide.

Comment: It sounds like you should store the `timestamp` of the last call in some state that lives outside of the widget(s) for this screen. How to do that depends on your state management approach, but in general you'll have some top-level state and this `timestamp` should be stored there.

Comment: But how will i change if for example the user reaches the limit and exists the app?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to persist the timestamp of each password reset request and check against it before allowing a new request at every time.

You can use a more persistent storage solution, such as shared preferences. Where every time you fetch it and after reset save it.

In try block first do this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<int> callTimes = prefs.getStringList('callTimes')?.map((e) => int.parse(e))?.toList() ?? [];
```

Now after resetting the password save it to local db:

```
prefs.setStringList('callTimes', callTimes.map((e) => e.toString()).toList());
```

In this way call times will be persisted even when the user navigates to another view or restarts the app.